# Exact solution for propagator with general quadratic potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, path-integral, propagator

Given the Hamiltonian:

$$H = \frac{1}{2m}p^2 + x_i M^{ij} x_j.$$

Is there an exact non-relativistic propagator for this, where $M$ is a general symmetric matrix? Similar to the [harmonic oscillator propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator). I expect it might be able to be done by diagonalising $M$ or a change of variables but I'm not really sure if this question has a well formed solution at all.

Comment: Is not homework just my curiosity.

Comment: "but I'm not really sure how to do it" do you mean you don't know how to diagonalise a symmetric matrix?

Comment: @fqq yeah I know how to diagonalise a matrix. I don't know how if this question has a well-formed solution. (I edited the question to make this clearer).

Comment: Have you tried writing the Hamiltonian with the diagonalised matrix?

Comment: @fqq, Yes, but then what do I do will all the diagonal values? Just take the square roots of them and put it in the equation? It doesn't seem to work. If I change variables in the $x$ they are no longer in the same direction as the $p$

Comment: Check again, it does work. It's just a rotation.

Answer (score 3):

You can make an ${\rm SO}(N)$  rotation that decouples the problem into a set of independent operators with frequencies given by the eigenvalues of $M$ and so generalize the  real-time  Feynman-Souriau-Horvathy formula
$$
K(x,x',t)=\exp\left\{-i\frac{\pi}{2}\left (\frac 1 2 +\left \lfloor  \frac{\omega t}{\pi}\right \rfloor\right)\right\} \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\pi \hbar |\sin \omega t|}}\\
\times \exp\left\{ \frac{im\omega}{2\hbar \sin\omega t}\left[ (x^2+{x'}^2)\cos\omega t -2xx'\right]\right\}.
$$

ForEuclidean time
H.M.Fried, in his book *Green functions and Ordered Exponentials*, has some related formulae such as that for symmetric matrices ${\bf A}$, ${\bf B}$ we have
$$
\exp\left\{\frac 12  \nabla^T {\bf A}\nabla \right\}  \exp\left\{-\frac 12 {\bf x}^T {\bf B}{\bf x} \right\}  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(1+{\bf AB})}} \\
\times \exp\left\{-\frac 1 2 {\bf x}^T{\bf B}(1+\bf{AB})^{-1}{\bf x} \right\}.
$$

Also for Euclidean time there is J.D. Louck's [*Extension of the Kibble-Slepian formula for Hermite polynomials using boson operator methods*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0196-8858(81)90005-1)

Comment: Hmm.. yes, I guess you'd rotate the system to point in the directions of the eignevectors. Still not exactly sure how to use those eigenvalues in the equation though.... It seems quite complicated.

Comment: So does $K(x,y,x',y',t)=K(x,x',t)K(y,y',t)$ if they are decoupled?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what decoupled means.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it now.